# Angular 2 WYSWYG form builder

Tags: angular, typescript, formbuilder

I am looking for a Form builder that i can use in my angular 2 application.

I found many form builders built in angular 1.x but couldn't find one for angular 2.

here is the list of those which i found.

[Form.io](https://github.com/formio/ngFormBuilder)

[AngularJs form builder](http://angularjs.jqueryrain.com/angular-drag-drop-form-builder/)

[Schema form](http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html)

[Kelp 404 Angular form builder](http://kelp404.github.io/angular-form-builder/)

Need help if there is any form builder for angular 2 +

Comment: There are many available for angular 2 for ex: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/ or for more interface click here https://angular.io/resources/

Comment: @mayur I am looking for a form builder instead of form component

Answer (score 1):

Try https://form.io/ It supports angular 2 framework

Comment: It uses Angular One for form designer.